# How to add an item to an already populated SimpleCursorAdapter?

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor

I'm using CursorLoader to fetch categories from a content provider. The data is being populated in SimpleCursorAdapter and displayed in a dropdown menu (spinner).
The thing is, I need to add an additional item to the list that will be displayed first.
How can I do that?

Here is the code:

```
CursorLoader cl = new CursorLoader(Main2Activity.this, 
        ContentProvider.createUri(Category.class, null), null, null, null, 
        "name ASC");
Cursor cursor = cl.loadInBackground();
final SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(Main2Activity.this,
      android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
      cursor,
      new String[]{"name"},
      new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
      0);
cursor.close();
```

Comment: use `android.database.MergeCursor`, and no, your code using the loaders is wrong, you should read how to use [loader](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) framework

Comment: @Mike M. I don't mean header, I mean an additional entry. For example, Assuming I have these entries from the DB:
Category A
Category B
Category C
and I'd like to add an additional entry at the top, so it will look like this:
Category new
Category A
Category B
Category C